# posting the data from iPhone to server (parsing data )

Tags: ios, iphone

i am little bit confused in in uploading data on the server with **jsonserialization**

trying to send data like this but it make me uncomfortable,i don't how can i use this

my formate is like this

Registraion Service

URL               :    http://vps.XXXX.com/UserService.svc/XXXXX

```
RequestJson   :

{
    "RegDetails": {
        "Phone_Device_Id": "123",
        "Email_Id": “test@gmail.com",
        "First_Name": “testname”,
        "Last_Name": “testlastname,
        "DOB": "2014-02-11 00:00:00.000",
        "MemberShip_Type": "Annual"
    }
}


ResponseJson :   

{
    "Head": {
        "ResponseCode": "1",
        "ResponseText": "Success"
    },
 "UserDetails": {
        "UserId": "1"
    }
}
```

**MY METHODS**

-(void)sendReuest
{

```
NSString *Post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=XXXX&email=XXX@gmail.com&mobile=7894521456"];
NSData *Postdata = [Post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *PostLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[Postdata length]];


NSMutableURLRequest  *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vps.XXXXX.com/TestService.svc/XXXXX?"] ];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:PostLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:Postdata];
NSLog(@"%@",request);
NSURLConnection *theconnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(theconnection)
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}
```

}

The method above gives me an error now. Some times it gives me an entire html page and some times it gives me nothing.

Please give suggestion which the best to use .How to use .That's my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this solve with help this code

```
-(void)sendJsonDate
{
    NSString*finalvalue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"RegDetails\":{\"Email_Id\”:\”XXXX@gmail.com\",\"DOB\":\"04/02/1986\",\"First_Name\”:\”XXXX\”,\”Last_Name\”:\”XXX\”,\”Phone_Device_Id\":\"896\",\"MemberShip_Type\":\"Annual\"}}"];
    NSLog(@"Request: %@", finalvalue);
    NSData *myJSONData =[finalvalue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"myJSONString :%@", finalvalue);
    NSLog(@"myJSONData :%@", myJSONData);
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [myJSONData length]];
    NSLog(@"%@",postLength);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://vps.XXXXXXX.com/XXXXXXX.svc/XXXXXX”]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:myJSONData];
    NSLog(@"%@",request);

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"%@",theConnection);
    if (theConnection) {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSLog(@"%@",webData);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your

`NSData *Postdata = [Post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];`
with

`NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error ];`

Comment: But my json formate is like this { "RegDetails": { "Phone_Device_Id": "123", "Email_Id": “test@gmail.com", "First_Name": “testname”, "Last_Name": “testlastname, "DOB": "2014-02-11 00:00:00.000", "MemberShip_Type": "Annual" } } How can upload the data with formate

Comment: Just pass your dictionary object containing (Phone_device, email id...) with a key as RegDetails. rest will be handled automatically.

Comment: Replace NSString *Post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=Harish&email=hari@gmail.com&mobile=7894521456"]; with NSDictionary *aDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKey:@"your value",@"your key (like email),..similary for all keys];
Then pass this dictionary to another dictionary which contains key as RegDetails, and then pass this dictionary in your [finalvalue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; by replacing final value with aDict.

Comment: i didn't get you can you explain more

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me write a code for you :)

```
-(void)test
{
       NSDictionary *aDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Harish",@"name",@"XXXX@gmail.com",@"email",@"123445",@"mobile", nil];


    NSData * Postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:aDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:Nil ];
     NSString *PostLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[Postdata length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest  *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vps.XXXX.com/TestService.svc/XXX1?"] ];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:PostLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:Postdata];
    NSLog(@"%@",request);
    NSURLConnection *theconnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(theconnection)
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}
```

I think it might work, if not send me the url and request format.

Comment: it give me error <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>

Comment: does this requeri authorisation? also tell header type

Comment: There is no authorisation required

Comment: no there are no headers in  it. just look above which i post the code method-(void)sendJsonDate which you done test code
working correctly but need it in proper way .and i also want know how can upload video with this?

Comment: i have tried this with all alternatives in rest client, i think there is an issue from web service side, because everytime i also get the html page in return.

Comment: so what was the issue

Comment: You can confirm from web service end if the ws is properly working or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47815/discussion-between-harish-and-rahul-mathur)